# How can I make this code faster (without using a loop)?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do this to a numpy array `x_new` in every loop. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
for i in range(nup):
    for j in range(nup):
        if j==i+1:
            x_new[i]=x_new[i]-U1[i]*x_old[j]
        elif j==i-1:
            x_new[i]=x_new[i]-L1[j]*x_old[j]
        elif j==i+nf:
            x_new[i]=x_new[i]-U2[i]*x_old[j]
        elif j==i-nf:
            x_new[i]=x_new[i]-L2[j]*x_old[j]
```

when `nup` is big, it takes way too long.

Comment: I didn't mark your question negative, but we really need the whole code or at least all the variables defined: nup, U1, L1, U2, L2, x_old, np, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize the loop by removing the inner loop and replacing the `j` values with the expressions used in the conditionals. This way, you directly access the required indices without iterating through all the possible values of `j`:

```
for i in range(nup):
    if i + 1 < nup:
        x_new[i] -= U1[i] * x_old[i + 1]
    if i - 1 >= 0:
        x_new[i] -= L1[i - 1] * x_old[i - 1]
    if i + nf < nup:
        x_new[i] -= U2[i] * x_old[i + nf]
    if i - nf >= 0:
        x_new[i] -= L2[i - nf] * x_old[i - nf]
```

This optimization reduces the time complexity from `O(nup^2)` to `O(nup)`, which should significantly speed up the loop.